# C# Cancel Windows Shutdown Programmatically

Tags: c#, process, shutdown

I have found online that I can schedule for windows to shutdown doing so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Shutdown
    Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 10");

}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel Shutdown
    Process.Start("shutdown /a");
}
```

So I have tied to a button an even that calls the above.  Is there a way for me to tie to another button a command that will cancel this shutdown?

I have search and haven;t found anything useful, I have found some stuff like

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "shutdown /a");
or
Process.Start("shutdown /a");
```

But neither of those seem to work.

Calling Process.Start("shutdown /a"); results in

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Comment: can you show the code of the button event ? perhaps you need to do it where you can check `CanCancel` but can't tell based on what little bit of code you have provided

Comment: To do it properly, look up WM_QUERYENDSESSION (http://hintdesk.com/c-catch-shutdown-event-of-computer/). There is also the SessionEnding event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the Message and possibly StackTrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start("shutdown", "/a");

will work when a shutdown has been scheduled using

Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 60");

but it will not cancel a shutdown that has already been initiated (i.e. The 60 seconds have elapsed).

This is just using the built in commands in windows:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491003.aspx